# Where can I find Wisp Essence?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I am trying to get Knight Enchanter.

I had my Wisp Essences from Fallow Mire, but they have disappeared.
Now when I go back to Fallow Mire, I can no longer find any.

Is there any other way to get Wisp Essences?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 Pure Wisp's in Fallow Mire that drop Wisp Essence. I had to go back recently to find the last 1 so I could complete the quest.

According to the [dragon age wiki](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Wisp_Essence) Wisp Essence can also be dropped by Wraiths at any Rifts.